# permutate number combinations with row total criteria and flexible order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a matrix with all possible number combinations given k numbers and a row sum of 1. One simple example:

numbers = [0, 0.5, 1]

These numbers need to permutated into a matrix with all possible combinations of the numbers adding up to 1. It is important that all k numbers are present. In this simple case the end result should be like this. All numbers are present and every row adds up to 1:

```
d = {'1': [1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0], '2': [0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5], '3':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5]}
```

So far, I've tried with itertools.permutations trough the code below:

```
numbers = list(itertools.permutations([0,0.5,1], 3))
```

However, I struggle to get the desired result under the given criteria. I speculate that I should apply itertools in combination with some conditional statement of the row value sum.

Anyone care to help? Would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Some points that make this question completely confusing. The expected output is not a matrix. The "rows" do not add up to 1. Why does the length of each row contain 6 elements? ...?

Comment: but I think in sample `[1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0]` every row is adds up to 2?

Comment: If you sum vector per vector , you will have [1,1,1,1,...] , I think that is what he means ?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick start**

This is just a brief recap + advice when coming to this problem.

1. Try to edit your question until everyone understands : the easier it is for everyone to understand, the easier it will seem in your mind as well.
2. Your problem is linked to combination but not exactly as you think so:

If you turn your problem upside down :

*For each colum*

- First, decide if you want a `1`, or 2 `0.5`.
- Then choose (combination-wise) the indices for these elements

*Display the matrix*

- Create a [0]* n*n matrix
- For each column, fill in what you have decided on the above.

If you do it correctly, you should have a cartesian product of size

- Number of possibilities for a columns
  *
- Number of columns